# How to change an image selected from another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got this code to change the image from a image list of then.
I'm trying to show a new window with the image list to choose one.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="service-icon">
            <img style='margin:0; padding:0; border:0;' id="imgGaleria" onclick="imgSeleccionada='imgGaleria';" src="img/Modulo1.jpg" />
            <img style='margin:0; padding:0; border:0;' id="imgGaleria2" onclick="imgSeleccionada='imgGaleria2';" src="img/Modulo2.jpg" />
            <img style='margin:0; padding:0; border:0;' id="imgGaleria3" onclick="imgSeleccionada='imgGaleria3';"  src="img/Modulo3.jpg" />

            <div id="galeria_miniaturas">
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo5.jpg';" src="img/Modulo5.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo6.jpg';" src="img/Modulo6.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo7.jpg';" src="img/Modulo7.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo8.jpg';" src="img/Modulo8.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo9.jpg';" src="img/Modulo9.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo10.jpg';" src="img/Modulo10.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo11.jpg';" src="img/Modulo11.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo12.jpg';" src="img/Modulo12.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(imgSeleccionada).src='img/Modulo13.jpg';" src="img/Modulo13.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wheres your Javascript? Can you provide a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This question is bad writted and doesn't explain what is the problem and where. Please, write all explanation or we need to close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have a image with id imgSeleccionada
   So I added one there is no need to set ID on click on one image,

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="service-icon">
            <img style='margin:0; padding:0; border:0;' id="imgSeleccionada" src="img/Modulo1.jpg" />
            <div id="galeria_miniaturas">
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo5.jpg';" src="img/Modulo5.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo6.jpg';" src="img/Modulo6.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo7.jpg';" src="img/Modulo7.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo8.jpg';" src="img/Modulo8.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo9.jpg';" src="img/Modulo9.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo10.jpg';" src="img/Modulo10.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo11.jpg';" src="img/Modulo11.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo12.jpg';" src="img/Modulo12.jpg" />
                <img class="miniatura" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imgSeleccionada').src='img/Modulo13.jpg';" src="img/Modulo13.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Try above code
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x97Lpyhh/4/)